# When reputation is 15, do previously cast votes get displayed?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

As I currently only have a reputation of 8, if I upvote a question I see the message "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." When I reach 15 reputation, will my upvotes be included from that point onwards, or are my current upvotes stored for the future? If the latter, I'll keep upvoting helpful questions and answers, but I won't bother until I reach 15 reputation if they're not being recorded. I'm assuming they aren't recorded, but as the wording seems ambiguous I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Only your votes when your reputation is >= 15 are recorded and displayed. Your votes when your reputation is < 15 is probably recorded along with "feedback votes" from anonymous users, and they are not displayed.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/did-something-change-in-the-behavior-of-blocking-users-votes-if-they-dont-have/259591#comment846221_259591

Comment: I agree that the wording is ambiguous.

Comment: Even in 2023, the text is poor. *"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."* I just introduced SO to my young brother and encouraged him to upvote both Questions and Answers. Now I will have to apologize to him and tell him to **not bother**. This is disappointing, I really thought it would apply his votes retroactively.

Comment: The wording is confusing, but the issue of whether the votes count retroactively or not should not confuse anyone at all. You cannot cast **actual votes** until you've earned that privilege (currently at 15 points), which means any votes cast before that privilege is earned DO NOT count as actual votes. You do not get any credit retroactively - if you did, you would have been voting before you earned the privilege to do so, which would defeat the entire purpose of requiring a minimum amount of rep at all.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> When I reach 15 reputation, will my upvotes be included from that point onwards?

Yes, your **new** upvotes will be applied.

> Are my current upvotes stored for the future?

No. You will have to revisit the old Q&As and upvote them again to improve their ratings.

Comment: The same goes for Down votes, at 125 reputation

Comment: Does this mean that even though it says *"your feedback has been recorded"*, it won't be applied once the user reaches 15 reputation? If yes, then the text is misleading. I really thought it would apply the votes retroactively. So disappointing and discouraging.

Comment: @Qwerty Precisely what it says happens happens though i.e. it's recorded as feedback. If you have 10K rep you can see that feedback in the aggregate, even for people who don't ever cross the threshold to be able to up or downvote.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't follow, you made it even more confusing. Are the **votes**, **feedback** and **aggregate** synonymous or completely different things? Are you saying that only people with 10+k rep will see the *votes recorded as feedback* as actual votes? In other words: Answer has 10 upvotes. A person with <15 upvotes it, they will see the answer still has 10 upvotes. Other users with <10k will see the answer has 10 upvotes. Other users with >10k will see the answer has 11 upvotes? Once the OG gets >15rep, their "feedback" will turn into actual votes, so the answer now has 11 votes?

Comment: @qwerty if you have 10K you can see a separate feedback page. That shows what feedback questions have received. Feedback and votes are always completely separate.

Comment: I see, thank you @RobertLongson. Last thing: can you please point me to documentation about this and where I can see the feedback on an actual QA? I have never noticed it, I do have enough rep. Googling "SO feedback page" is rather difficult.

Comment: @Qwerty https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback - you can get there from the links at the bottom of the [tools page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools)