# Do my invisible downvotes become visible after I reached 125 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125
>   reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post
>   score.

Will the downvotes I casted *before* 125 reputation be publicly displayed *after* I reached 125 reputation?

Comment: no, they aren't actually downvotes and are recorded differently.

Comment: @CodyGray The answer to my question happens to be in that question, but I don't think they're duplicate questions.

Comment: @Metoniem It's not a requirement for the questions to be duplicates. If the answer to another question answers this question, then it's a valid duplicate target.

Comment: @Stijn Oh, I see.

Comment: But perhaps http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302885/when-reputation-is-15-do-previously-cast-votes-get-displayed is a better duplicate target. (I've already used my close vote on Cody's suggestion though)

Comment: @Stijn I agree, that definitely looks like a better target. I already clicked "This answers my question" though, can the target question still be changed now?

Comment: It can, by having a bunch of people (or a moderator) reopen the question and then close it again. Not worth the trouble for this question, I think, unless a moderator sees this and feels like doing it.

Comment: Why do you not think it's a duplicate? You and Preethi literally quote the same message and ask the same thing.

Comment: @CodyGray As you can read above the reason why it's a duplicate was explained to me already, I _do_ think it's a duplicate now! :P

Comment: Right, I get that you somehow thought it was a different question that happened to be the same answer. But I cannot understand that perspective. As I said, you and the person who asked that question literally quote the same system message and ask for an explanation of what it means.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, I thought my vote counted but just wasn't displayed to the public, whereas he already knew it didn't count at all, and he was just wondering what the message meant. I _thought_ I understood the message, but didn't know if my vote would be displayed after I reached 125 reputation. Either way, I understand that it's a duplicate now, so I guess all is good now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't. [Some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/change-the-wording-of-thank-you-for-your-feedback-when-a-user-below-125-re), the wording of the message was changed in an attempt to clarify this.

Quoting [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326061/247702):

> Folks - particularly folks who already know how all of this works - tend to get hung up on the wording here, assuming that it means voting will become retroactive at 125 rep or something. If that's your concern, then focus on eliminating the ambiguity *without* destroying the educational purpose of the message.