# Why not show upvotes in profile even without having '15' reputation?

Tags: feature-request, voting, upvotes

Currently when casting votes on Stack Overflow with reputation less than 15, the message, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." is displayed. Once you are past reputation 15 on a particular site, the upvotes are then shown in your profile. Without having 15 reputation, it is only possible to favorite the questions.

My question is; Why can't the upvotes still be shown in my profile on a site where I don't have 15 reputation? This goes especially if the upvotes are actually stored, as the message seems to suggest. I'd like to still be able to see answers that I have upvoted, even without having yet gained the reputation.

Comment: Related: [When reputation is 15, do previously cast votes get displayed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302885/7795130), as well as [What does it mean when it says my vote is “recorded” but “does not change the publicly displayed posted score”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339184/7795130). Of course, neither of these show the reason why, just the mechanics behind it.

Comment: Servy's answer on the second link mentions how those votes can be queried, but it's anonymized, so you can't tell which votes were yours.

Comment: Votes cast before you have 15 rep do not count (even after you've earned 15 rep), so there's no point in showing them. What purpose would it serve showing you votes you cast that have absolutely no relevance to anything? You can earn 15 rep with a few edits that are approved, probably in less than an hour.

Comment: @KenWhite I frequently go back through posts I've upvoted, because they're often interesting and I'd like to browse them again. Users might be curious like that, or they might want to cast a real vote once they've earned that right. This seems useful enough to me to warrant including, if a developer happened to be working in that part of the code.

Comment: @Jeremy: That's what favorites are for, not upvotes. Favorites can be used with zero rep, as long as you have an account.

Comment: @Jeremy: Whether that's true or not (I use favorites, and while I don't think they're greatly implemented, they're still useful for what you describe), and mis-using upvotes for the purpose of marking interesting posts isn't really appropriate. Votes are not designed to be used that way, and that's not the intent of voting. New users shouldn't be using them that way, either. If the favorites feature isn't working well, we should be trying to get it changed so that it works better.

Comment: Note: this is not a duplicate, the duplicate question is tagged [support] and this [feature-request], so they haven't any relationship at all!

Comment: @KenWhite: Your comment could actually be the answer to this question! I'll consider about modifying this as a feature request for adding the favorites, or similar  functionality to the answers too. Then again, that would actually be a duplicate (of a duplicate..): [Why there is no favorite answer tag on answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269814/can-we-favorite-an-answer-instead-of-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

Three reasons; pick any you like:

- The developers didn't think of it.
- It'd slow down the list to have a `JOIN` in it.
- The developers don't have time to program it.