# Will the answerer know they were voted up while I have less than 15 reputation points?

Tags: support, upvotes

I want to say 'thank you' for the answers that I have found very helpful. But when I push the 'Vote' button I receive the message:

> "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15
> reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post
> score."

I understand from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302885/when-reputation-is-15-do-previously-cast-votes-get-displayed) that when I finally reach 15 points these votes will be publicly shown.

But does the user who wrote the answer know that they were voted up prior to me reaching the elusive 15 points?

For clarification, I don't mean 'Do they know the *name* of the person who upvoted them'. I do mean, is my effort to say 'thank you' by voting them up a waste of time since they never actually receive any notification of any type that I voted their answer up.

Comment: Nobody ever knows who up/down voted regardless of reputation.

Comment: Your last sentence suggests that you're asking "does the author of a post know when *some* user with less than 15 rep up-votes it?" Or are you actually asking if the author knows *which* user up-voted?

Comment: @yivi They don't get rep?

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Related Meta.SE post: [Where can I see questions and answers I've upvoted if I have less than 15 reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352805/348196)

Comment: Thanks for the info (and upvoting - I made it to 15 finally!). I modified the question a little to make it more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Answer inspired on a now deleted answer by [Jeanne Dark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11682469/jeanne-dark)*

**No**, the answerer or visitors can't tell on the site.

If your reputation is below 15 (or 125 for downvotes) your upvotes are only internal feedback. You're not actually voting. As [Shog9 explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259591):

> No, it means you're not voting. You're leaving "feedback" — we track the nature of your vote, but don't alter the post score in response to it.

If you're curious you can query [SEDE for the PostFeedback table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1337772) that will hold the mentioned feedback.

Up and down votes are always anonymous. Nobody knows who voted or exactly at what time.

Comment: Feedback is also shown in the 10k tools, but none of the views there are particularly good, especially not if you’re looking for specific posts.